# JQuery not working in JSFiddle when adding as new

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

This is the code

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectChange" name="selectChange">
    <option value='1' >One</option>
    <option value='2' >Two</option>
    <option value='3' >Three</option>
    <option value='4' >Four</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#selectChange').change(function(){
        alert( $(this).val());
    });
```

I created a JSFiddle for JQuery on select change event. [This is the link to that.](http://jsfiddle.net/ATFhv/)
As you can see, it is not working.

Then I got one JSFidle working link for JQuery on select change event form SO answer.(Don't remeber where.)

Then I updated the code to the one I already wrote in the previous link.
[This is the updated JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wzzMm/29/) . And it is working fine. If ypu remove the ***/29/*** from this second URL, you can see the old JSFidle link.

You can see both the code are same. But why the first one is not working? Whenever I try to create a new JSFiddle for JQuery, I'm not able to perform it and I need to check for any already existing one and update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select a version of jQuery in the first drop down below the heading *Frameworks & Extensions*.

At the moment it's set to **No library (Pure JS)**. This means jQuery is not available to use.